# Google Analytics inside Document ready not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quick question about the reason **why**  this **works**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

And **this**  **does not**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
});
</script>
```

What is the thing that blocks analytics to run with the document ready?

Comment: any reason why you're doing this in jquery's "ready" event?

Comment: @Xander For cookie policy warning. Didn't include the implementation. Ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `_gaq` variable declaration to global scope

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
$(function(){
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  ...
```

or make `window._gaq` property to use with google analytics

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  window.gaq = window._gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It likely has to do with the JavaScript code that Google itself is loading into the DOM. Which is likely set to run at document load (or some other readystate/load event). Since the script is being executed when the DOM is ready (`jQuery.load`) GA won't execute as the ready event already fired.

If that isn't the issue, then it could be a scoping issue.