# Google analytics from jQuery's document.ready() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, document-ready

I am trying to find a way to add google analytics code from a document.ready() function. The following code doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             var _gaq = window._gaq || [];
                 _gaq.push(['e._setAccount', 'UA-XXXZZ-1']);
                 _gaq.push(['e._setDomainName', 'company.com']);
                 _gaq.push(['e._trackPageview']);
                 _gaq.push(['a._setAccount', 'UA-XXXYY-1']);
                 _gaq.push(['a._setDomainName', 'company.com']);
                 _gaq.push(['a._trackPageview']);

                 (function() {
                       var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                       ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                 })();      
});
```

What could the solution be? I can put the piece of code which creates link to ga.js file inside the head tag, but will it solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you add it to the document.ready function ? Just paste it into a script block onto the page and it will do its work !

Comment: Google Analytics has specific installation instructions. If you follow them it works. There's no need to place their code in `$document.ready()`

Comment: I want to do A-B content testing with google analytics and the A-B testing script must fire before the GA script. However, because of CMS limitations all page specific scripts are placed after the site-wide script (which GA code is). So I need to find a way to run GA code after all other scripts in the head tag have been loaded.

Comment: Use the Google Tag Manager and set the rules to trigger the GA tag to "gtm.dom" (their equivalent of document.ready). However you still need to place the experiment code directly into  the site (won't work from the Tag Manager). Tag managemen is a good idea in any case.

Comment: Hi Eike, you seem to understand the issue and I would like to ask a question. Do you know whether it is wrong to put GA code inside document.ready()? I can't really find any proper information about it. My solution, which is posted below, seems to work. Is it not reliable in any way?

Answer (score 1):

The following setup seems to work fine: 
in the page head add this script, which runs immediately:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

in document ready add the tracking code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var _gaq = window._gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['e._setAccount', 'UA-XXXZZ-1']);
      _gaq.push(['e._setDomainName', 'company.com']);
      _gaq.push(['e._trackPageview']);
      _gaq.push(['a._setAccount', 'UA-XXXYY-1']);
      _gaq.push(['a._setDomainName', 'company.com']);
      _gaq.push(['a._trackPageview']); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete $(document).ready(function(){

and document ready closing tag => });

Because google analytic not work in side document ready function

Comment: could you please explain why it won't or provide a link where this is explained?

Comment: this link from google
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

but in your code 
$(function() {  ............. == same with $(document).ready

i think can solve :D

Comment: sorry, both are 'no'. Your link just gives a guidance where to place the GA code, and $(function()) and document.ready() do a bit different things

Comment: about document.ready() and $(function) you were technically right.  I just realized that confusion is because I didn't provide all code that I have inside the document ready, I my example it makes no sense to use both :)

Answer (score 0):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226726/google-analytics-inside-document-ready-not-working) answers it for you and masadi was on the right track:

The document `ready` function means the scope of the `_gaq` variable is too limited. When the rest of the Google script in ga.js runs it can't find the variable. By moving the `_gaq` stuff up into the global scope (outside of any other function or using `window.gaq`) the variable can be found.

The only advantage of putting it in document `ready` is to make sure the DOM is complete before the analytics run. For me this was because the script was called before `<title>` was set and I was otherwise getting blank titles.